# rails 6 has_one relation error "can't write unknown attribute `#{name}`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I' am using rails 6.1 and I trying to define a has_one relation, this is my current model definitions:

```
class Session < ApplicationRecord

  self.implicit_order_column = 'created_at'

  belongs_to :consultant
  belongs_to :professional
  has_one :session_summary, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'session_summary_id'

end

class SessionSummary < ApplicationRecord

  validates :objectives, presence: true

  belongs_to :session, foreign_key: 'session_summary_id'
end
```

and these are my migrations:

```
class CreateSessionSummaries < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :session_summaries do |t|
      t.string :objectives, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateSessions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :sessions, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_reference :sessions, :professional, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :sessions, :consultant, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :sessions, :session_summary, type: :bigint, null: false, foreign_key: true, index: { unique: true }
  end
end
```

but when I run some code like this:

```
s= Session.new
ss = SessionSummary.new

s.session_summary = s
```

I got this error:

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-6.1.7.6/lib/active_model/attribute.rb:207:in `with_value_from_database': can't write unknown attribute `session_summary_id` (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)

          raise ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError, "can't write unknown attribute `#{name}`"
          ^^^^^
```

what could be wrong on my definitions?

Comment: There is a typo in s.session_sumary.

Comment: thanks for the comments, well the errors is not by the type(already adjusted), but @engineersmnky my intention is to have a session as a strong entity, so the session_summary belongs to the session and the session is part of the work of the professional..... anyways I will try to invert the relation

Comment: @engineersmnky, you're right invert the relation works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add_reference :sessions, :session_summary` is inconsistent with:

```
class Session  
  has_one :session_summary
```

For a `HasOne` relationship the `session_id` would be stored in the `session_summaries` table but your migration adds `session_summary_id` to the `sessions` table. [`add_reference` Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)

Given that you want a `Session` to have one and only one `SummarySession` you should just be able change the migration from

```
add_reference :sessions, :session_summary, type: :bigint, null: false, foreign_key: true, index: { unique: true }
```

To (note the change in type as well)

```
add_reference :session_summaries, :session, type: :uuid, null: false, foreign_key: true, index: { unique: true }
```

The relationships are natural so the `foreign_key` in the classes is not necessary

Comment: Theoretically you could also just switch up the `belongs_to` and `has_one` relationships, as it is not really important for rails which part of the relationship holds the foreign key. Personally I would go with your approach here though, because for me it feels more natural to have the foreign key on the session summary, but that's purely from a modelling point of view

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau technically true and honestly I would have expected session to belong_to summary as originally designed but also that summary has_many sessions however, that is not what the desired outcome was per the comment.